# How can I link two different parse databases to an app based on the scheme?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I want to link two different databases in parse to my app. One for testing and one for PPE. I want to be able to change which backend the data comes from by just switching the scheme. How do I do this?

Comment: So when you run the app it is only connected to one, and you choose what to run to decide what to connect to?

Comment: Yes. Right now I only have it connected to one database with this code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate with my app Id and client key filled in: Parse.setApplicationId(" ", clientKey: "") but I want to link it to another database as well. Then I want to be able to change the database the app uses just by changing the scheme

Comment: So you know it's scheme related, did you create multiple targets? What problem are you having with that?

Comment: I figured out how to create multiple targets. So now i have my original build target and then another for PPE

Comment: I just can't figure out how to connect one target to one database and the other target to the other database

Comment: What I frequently do in these situations is create a routine that detects my environment. That could be based on the host machine name or an ip address. Another good trick is to use an env.properties file that is static on each machine because it is not a part of source control. The system determines in which environment it is running and substitutes the database url accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest and fastest is to define a preprocessor macro and then check that in the code with `#ifdef`. if it's defined then use 1 URL and if it isn't user the other one.